# Convert colors from RGB to NV12

Tags: c++, windows, h.264, hlsl, ms-media-foundation

I’m working on an app that encodes video with media foundation h264 encoder. Sink writer [crashes on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52324521/126995) with RGB input in VRAM, saying "0x8876086C D3DERR_INVALIDCALL" so I’ve implemented my own RGB->NV12 conversion on GPU, saving more than 60% of PCI express bandwidth.

Here’s what in my media types, both input (NV12) and output (h264):

```
mt->SetUINT32( MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING, MFVideoChromaSubsampling_MPEG2 ); // Specifies the chroma encoding scheme for MPEG-2 video. Chroma samples are aligned horizontally with the luma samples, but are not aligned vertically. The U and V planes are aligned vertically.
mt->SetUINT32( MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX, MFVideoTransferMatrix_BT709 ); // ITU-R BT.709 transfer matrix.
mt->SetUINT32( MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE, MFNominalRange_0_255 ); // The normalized range [0...1] maps to [0...255] for 8-bit samples or [0...1023] for 10-bit samples.
mt->SetUINT32( MF_MT_TRANSFER_FUNCTION, MFVideoTransFunc_10 );  // Linear RGB (gamma = 1.0).
```

The best result so far I have with this formula:

```
inline float3 yuvFromRgb(float3 rgba)
{
    float3 res;
    res.x = dot( rgba, float3( 0.182585880, 0.614230573, 0.0620070584 ) );
    res.y = dot( rgba, float3( -0.121760942, -0.409611613, 0.531372547 ) );
    res.z = dot( rgba, float3( 0.531372547, -0.482648790, -0.0487237722 ) );
    res += float3( 0.0627451017, 0.500000000, 0.500000000 );
    return saturate( res );
}
```

What worries me is the formula contradicts everything I’ve read on the internet, code samples, and official ITU specs.

For Y the formula’s fine, I took BT.709 coefficients, and scaled them linearly to map [0..255] into [16..235] as written in the spec. The brightness is OK.

The specs say I must scale U and V to map from [0..255] into [16..240]. My eyes, however, tell me it’s undersaturated. For correct colors I have to scale U & V the other way, from [0..255] into something like [-8, 255 + 8].

Why do I need to scale the other way to achieve correct colors after h264 encoding & decoding? Will this code work on other people’s computers?

Comment: Did you read this :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/yuv-format-ranges
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/about-yuv-video
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/recommended-8-bit-yuv-formats-for-video-rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was chroma sampling artifacts. When I asked the question, I was looking at colored console text.

Today I’ve tried encoding better image, this one: [image] With that image, it became obvious the correct formula is what’s specified in these standards.

So, here’s the correct coefficients:

```
// Convert RGB color into ITU-R BT.709 YUV color
inline float3 yuvFromRgb( float3 rgb )
{
    float3 res;
    res.x = dot( rgb, float3( 0.18258588, 0.61423057, 0.06200706 ) );
    res.y = dot( rgb, float3( -0.10064373, -0.33857197, 0.43921569 ) );
    res.z = dot( rgb, float3( 0.43921569, -0.39894217, -0.04027352 ) );
    res += float3( 0.06274510, 0.50196081, 0.50196081 );
    return res;
}
```

They still give me off-by-one error but for my particular problem, that 0.39% error is acceptable.

Comment: So what is chroma sampling artifacts ? where is formula standards ? where did 0.39% come from ? Do you just discovered that using standard formula is the right way to do ?

Comment: “what is chroma sampling artifacts?” try to h264 encode colored text over black background, and you’ll see. “where is formula standards?” In the standards. The main one is ITU-R BT.709.  If you’ll care to read them and do some basic math, you’ll get the coefficients in my pixel shader. “where did 0.39% come from?” In my tests, I saw off-by-one difference on some colors i.e. #aabccc instead of #aabbcc after encoding+decoding. 1 / 255 = 0.39%. “Do you just discovered that using standard formula is the right way to do?” Yes I did.

Comment: @mofo77 BTW, despite h264 is widespread, there’s no code on the internets with the correct YUV formula. That’s the main reason why I answered my question instead of just deleting it.

Comment: Also, in production I don’t have a single YUV shader. It’s split in 2, one for luma that reads from single pixel and writes to R8_UNORM target, another one for combined U+V that reads from 2 pixels and writes to R8G8_UNORM target. I hope my sample code will help people making something similar.

Comment: so your formula is for 8-bit coding, not 10-bit coding. perhaps it should be precised. Doing some basic math does not explain where your values come from.

Comment: @mofo77 My formula runs on GPU and operates on floating point values. If you need 10 bits output you can use R16_UNORM and R16G16_UNORM render targets but then you’ll need one more step to pack 16 bit values into 10, e.g. a compute shader. The values are derived from two parts of the standard, “Derivation of luminance and color difference signals” defining color model, another one “Quantization levels” defining ranges. I’ve multiplied them together to produce a single formula.

Comment: Ok, If you edit your aswer, i could undo the downvote.

Comment: Going through several formulas and the resulting values, it seems that most online YUV conversion examples are using the T871 standard which is designed for JPEG images. That is not correct for displaying video. So this answer is perfect for devs who quickly want to convert RGB into BT.709